# substract a string based on a pattern

Tags: r, regex, string, subtraction

I have the following string in R:

```
[1]"1128=9,9=277,35=X,49=CME,34=12651"
[2]"1128=9,9=277,35=X,34=114,49=CBOT,38=126"
```

Now I want to get the character CME and CBOT which is ALWAYS after 49= and before a comma.

The result should be like

```
[1] CME
[2] CBOT
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `gsub(".*49= *(.*?) *,.*", "\\1", "1128=9,9=277,35=X,49=CME,34=12651")`

Comment: You could also use `regmatches(s, regexpr('(?<=49=)([A-z])*(?=,)', s, perl = TRUE))` where `s` is your character vector.

Comment: Thanks! it works? I am not familiar with regular expressions, could you please be more kind and explain what do those expressions mean? Many thanks!

Comment: @ZhepengHu Too lazy to do the google thing, eh? See [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) and [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html) and [here](http://stat545.com/block022_regular-expression.html) and [here](http://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-use-regular-expressions-in-r/) ... and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)
df %>% 
  mutate(new=stri_split_fixed(df$V1, "49=", simplify = T)[,2]) %>% 
  mutate(new=stri_extract_first_words(new))
                                       V1  new
1       1128=9,9=277,35=X,49=CME,34=12651  CME
2 1128=9,9=277,35=X,34=114,49=CBOT,38=126 CBOT
```